# replace field name using @JsonTypeInfo

Tags: java, json, jackson

I would like to know if there is a way to replace the fieldname using @JsonTypeInfo

Here is what I want to achieve

```
class Tnode<T>{

    @JsonTypeInfo(use=Id.NAME, include=As.WRAPPER_OBJECT, property="type")
    T obj;

    public T getObj() {
        return obj;
    }

    public void setObj(T obj) {
        this.obj = obj;
    }

}
```

I get output as

```
{
    "obj": {
        "Foo": {
            "name": "xyz"
        }
    }
}
```

The whole point is I do not want an extra layer "obj" as field name. I want the "Foo" to be one level above. In the code I am setting generic type to a concrete type. I want concrete class name to show up rather than having it wrapped.

I did try changing to include=As.PROPERTY but it will stil output as "obj".

I did solve using custom serializer. But I have to set every field.

```
public class CustomSerializer extends JsonSerializer<Object> {
    public void serialize(Object value, JsonGenerator jgen, SerializerProvider    provider) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        jgen.writeStartObject();
        jgen.writeObjectField("somename", value);
        jgen.writeEndObject();
    }
}
```

But the problem is when ever I have to add a instance variable in Tnode class I have to add that code in the custom serializer. And I want to avoid that.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do that. Name of the property to contain Object, wrapped in type information, has to be statically known (to locate logical property). It can not vary.